# How to compile a DirectX 11 app in MinGW

Tags: directx, mingw, directx-11

I've looked, and I can't find *any* material relating to using Direct3d 10 or 11 with MinGW. What do I have to do to get things working? I'm getting errors in the header files supplied by the DX SDK.

And don't anyone even *think* of suggesting Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that here it is explained how to get DX headers from SDK work with MinGW: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tbk/20110115/1295080728
Use Google Translate to translate page to english.

Alternatively try using DirectX headers from mingw64 project from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/
You'll need "Download headers and CRT source v2.0.1 (r4623) (7.0 MB)". Or you can check out them directly from svn: https://mingw-w64.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/mingw-w64/trunk/mingw-w64-headers/

Comment: I gave the suggestion from the Japanese site a try and also from  another site I found (since I needed IID numbers) and managed to compile a simply hello world DX11 program. Unfortunately it only seems to work for 32-bit. A 64-bit compile crashes. Also, I'm already using the latest version of MinGW-w64, and I had no luck with the DX11 headers included with it. I get errors due to to things like ID3D11Device not being defined etc.

Comment: @Chris_F did you link with the 64 bit directx library?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20081206035317/http://www.emmestech.com/moron_guides/moron1.html is the first link in English (had to use Wayback Machine).

Answer (score 3):

May be this is answer.

[http://www.gamedev.net/topic/619239-directx-11-mingw-w64/page_*view*_findpost_*p*_4908066](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/619239-directx-11-mingw-w64/page__view__findpost__p__4908066)