# How do I get MinGW to accept DirectX 11?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, directx-11, mingw-w64

After attempting the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005054/how-do-i-compile-a-directx-tutorial-sample-in-mingw) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000485/how-to-compile-a-directx-11-app-in-mingw), I got Eclipse to the point where it doesn't give me a bunch of errors while I'm writing my DX11 application.  The linker on the other hand, continues to give me some `undefined reference` errors.  Right now, it's just for `IID_IDXGIFactory` and `CreateDXGIFactory` simply because I haven't finished the `Initialize()` function and there's no other part of the code that uses the DirectX API.

What am I missing that is causing these errors in the linker?

Edit:  Libraries included are the x64 versions of `dxgi`, `dxguid`, `d3d10`, `d3dx10`, `d3d11` and `d3dx11` in that order.  I already know that not linking to the correct libraries causes `undefined reference` errors.  My question is, what am I missing?

Comment: Undefined reference error probably means you did not specify the correct libraries to link against. [see here for background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Libraries included are the x64 versions of `dxgi`, `dxguid`, `d3d10`, `d3dx10`, `d3d11` and `d3dx11` in that order.

Comment: I need something more definitive than "did not specify the correct libraries" as I already know that.

Comment: If you are using DirectX 11, then you do *not* need ``d3d10.lib`` or ``d3dx10.lib``. Also keep in mind that ``d3dx11.lib`` is deprecated along with the legacy DirectX SDK generally. See [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/) and [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/)