# DirectX header files not found (MinGW)

Tags: c++, directx, mingw

I am using MinGW compiler with the command line and sublime text 3. While including the header files for DirectX into my C++ code, it gave errors saying they weren't found.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
```

This results in the following error:

```
lesson 5.cpp:4:20: fatal error: d3dx11.h: No such file or directory
#include <d3dx11.h>
```

If I comment out the line it gave an error for, it just gives the same error for the next line.

Comment: They are not part of the standard library

Comment: You will have to add a `-I<path to directx headers>` to the compiler command. There's probably a duplicate for this hanging around. I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: You know, I can't find one for mingw, just for Visual Studio. This has me thinking that you might also run into a library mis-match problem. Might be some general help at [How to compile a DirectX 11 app in MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000485/how-to-compile-a-directx-11-app-in-mingw)

Comment: I tried downloading MinGW-W64 from the links, unless I am doing something wrong, it didn't work. Afterward i did a search on my whole C: drive to find the location of the missing header file (Searching for "d3dx11"). All that came up were the DLL files: d3dx11_43.dll, d3dx11_42.dll (both in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and \System32) I don't think there are the header files on my computer at all. Did I not download DirectX correctly?

Comment: I actually just found a location in my hard drive with directx headers. dxd11 is in there but the other two are not, should I just find a place to download those two? The location is "C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.2.2\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include".

Comment: ``D3DX10`` and ``D3DX11`` are utility libraries that only exist in the legacy DirectX SDK. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). You can and should avoid them in favor of open source replacements. See [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/)

Comment: @ChuchWalbourn Thank you for that info. I will try to see if I can get a 3D rendering without the legacy DirectX SDK. At the moment, I don't have any questions. When I am finished with getting it to work, I'll try to answer this thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile a DirectX 11 app in MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000485/how-to-compile-a-directx-11-app-in-mingw)